# Confused with breaks and looping in my program

Tags: c

> Use for loops to process the data for 5 employees.
> One loop to load the data
> One loop to print the output.
> In for loops, if any of the entered fields are –1, break out of the loop immediately after getting -1
> Update the output as shown in the sample data.
> Use arrays to store the user input.

I have a problem with breaking out of the loop. I think the system is reading it as an integer, not a character.

I also have a problem with looping the output. It is not looping the number of times the user has entered the info.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   char name[5][10];
   float hourswork[10];
   float hourspay[10];
   float grosspay[10];
   float taxes[10];
   float netpay[10];
   int i = 0;

   for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
   {
      printf("Hello, enter your name: \n");
      scanf("%s", &name[i][10]);

      printf("Enter your hourly wage: \n");
      scanf("%f", &hourspay[i]);

      printf("Enter the hours you have worked \n");
      scanf("%f", &hourswork[i]);

      if (hourswork[i] <= 40)
      {
         grosspay[i] = hourspay[i] * hourswork[i];
      }
      else if (hourswork[i] > 40)
      {
         grosspay[i] = (40 * hourspay[i]) + (((hourswork[i] - 40) * 1.5) * hourspay[i]);
      }

      taxes[i] = grosspay[i] * 0.2;
    
      if (name[i][10] == -1||hourspay[i] == -1||hourswork[i] == -1)
      {
         break;
      }
   }
    
   for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
   {
      printf("\n%c's Pay:\n", name[i][10]);

      printf("Hourly Rate: %.2f\n", hourspay[i]);

      printf("Hours Worked: %.2f\n", hourswork[i]);
      printf("Gross Pay: %.2f\n", grosspay[i]);
      printf("Taxes: %.2f\n", taxes[i]);

      netpay[i] = grosspay[i] - taxes[i];

      printf("Net Pay: %.2f\n\n", netpay[i]);
   }
```

Comment: You are going out of bounds with your `name` array with `name[i][10]`. The 2nd dimension's index value must be _less than_ 10.

Comment: Nothing about this code is C++, only C, so I have removed the `c++` tag. Also, see [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/)

Comment: `if (scanf ("%9s", name[i]) != 1) { /* handle error */ }`?? You must use the *field-width* modifier when reading into a character array to protect your array bounds (including space for the nul-terminating character). Otherwise, your use of `scanf()` is no safer than `gets()`. See [Why gets() is so dangerous it should never be used!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1694036/3422102) You must validate the return of `scanf()` to ensure the input succeeded (especially where numeric conversions are involved and a *matching failure* is possible)